# Sharepoint 2013 Can't view other users Notes on Note Board

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

We are experience an issue where on any list that allows the Notes and Tag functionality a user can only see their own notes. The notes are not set to private and the users have contribute permission. If I log into the list as the farm account I am able to view all Notes. What’s also strange is that once a new comment has been added. A user can’t delete or edit their old note and get the error:

> There was an error processing this request. Please refresh this page.

ULS of the Error

> 09/03/2014 11:07:15.02 w3wp.exe (0x23F8)   0x1F48  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (POST:`http://somesite:80/_layouts/15/socialdataframe.aspx?listid=%7BDE98DE8F%2D2BDE%2D4422%2D80A3%2DDA27DB83C2D1%7D&id=1&mode=0&IsDlg=1`) fdedb49c-3905-404b-9f46-34767cb86d58
>
> 09/03/2014 11:07:15.02 w3wp.exe (0x23F8)   0x1F48  SharePoint Foundation   General ajji6   High    Unable to write SPDistributedCache call usage entry.    fdedb49c-3905-404b-9f46-34767cb86d58
>
> 09/03/2014 11:07:15.04 w3wp.exe (0x23F8)   0x1F48  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Site=/  fdedb49c-3905-404b-9f46-34767cb86d58
>
> 09/03/2014 11:07:15.07 w3wp.exe (0x1408)   0x0FA8  SharePoint Foundation   Micro Trace uls4    Medium  Micro Trace Tags: 0 e5mb    fdedb49c-3905-404b-9f46-34767cb86d58
>
> 09/03/2014 11:07:15.08 w3wp.exe (0x23F8)   0x1F48  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    e5mc    High    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 09/03/2014 11:07:15.07, Original Level: Medium] WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: '{0}' Channel: '{1}' Action: '{2}' MessageId: '{3}' fdedb49c-3905-404b-9f46-34767cb86d58
>
> 09/03/2014 11:07:15.08 w3wp.exe (0x23F8)   0x1F48  SharePoint Foundation   General aipzv   High    Unable to write service call usage entry.   fdedb49c-3905-404b-9f46-34767cb86d58
>
> 09/03/2014 11:07:15.08 w3wp.exe (0x23F8)   0x1F48  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dka1    High    SearchServiceApplicationProxy::Execute--Proxy Name:Search Service Application EndPoint: `http://someapp:32843/70c8dc6bd21c4cf79650f638307cbf7a/SearchService.svc`   fdedb49c-3905-404b-9f46-34767cb86d58
>
> 09/03/2014 11:07:15.08 w3wp.exe (0x23F8)   0x1F48  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dk8z    High    SearchServiceApplicationProxy::GetChannel--Channel Creation time: 0 fdedb49c-3905-404b-9f46-34767cb86d58
>
> 09/03/2014 11:07:15.13 w3wp.exe (0x23F8)   0x1F48  SharePoint Foundation   General aipzv   High    Unable to write service call usage entry.   fdedb49c-3905-404b-9f46-34767cb86d58
>
> 09/03/2014 11:07:15.13 w3wp.exe (0x23F8)   0x1F48  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dk91    High    SearchServiceApplicationProxy::Execute--Id: Elapsed Time: 46 IMSProxyTime 30 QP Time: 18 Client Type MySiteSecurityTrimmer TenantId 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    fdedb49c-3905-404b-9f46-34767cb86d58
>
> 09/03/2014 11:07:15.13 w3wp.exe (0x23F8)   0x1F48  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dka2    High    SearchServiceApplicationProxy::Execute--Id: Elapsed Time: 46.8015 Proxy Name/ID: Search Service Application/8ccdc228-0dc7-49a1-a4e5-15329d0a4378 EndPoint: `http://somepapp:32843/70c8dc6bd21c4cf79650f638307cbf7a/SearchService.svc`   fdedb49c-3905-404b-9f46-34767cb86d58
>
> 09/03/2014 11:07:15.13 w3wp.exe (0x23F8)   0x1F48  Web Content Management  Publishing  ad87k   Medium  RewriteUrls:Link fix up code was called fdedb49c-3905-404b-9f46-34767cb86d58
>
> 09/03/2014 11:07:15.13 w3wp.exe (0x23F8)   0x1F48  Web Content Management  Publishing  ad87n   Medium  RewriteUrls:Link fix up code finished in 0ms time   fdedb49c-3905-404b-9f46-34767cb86d58
>
> 09/03/2014 11:07:15.13 w3wp.exe (0x23F8)   0x1F48  SharePoint Server   Social Data amcug   Unexpected  Error: Url returned from Search does not contain `HTTP://SOMESITE/LISTS/TEST LIST/DISPFORM.ASPX?ID=1`   fdedb49c-3905-404b-9f46-34767cb86d58
>
> 09/03/2014 11:07:15.13 w3wp.exe (0x23F8)   0x1F48  SharePoint Foundation   Micro Trace uls4    Medium  Micro Trace Tags: 0 ajji6,2 agb9s,38 ajk39,0 ajk35,0 ajk36,0 e5mc,8 aipzv,0 ajk37,0 ajk4a,2 dka1,0 dk8z,0 e5mc,45 aipzv,1 dk91,0 dka2,0 ad87k,0 ad87n,0 amcug,0 xppp    fdedb49c-3905-404b-9f46-34767cb86d58

Comment: Any updates on this? We are expericing tha same behaviour...

Comment: Still no luck with this. We have tried updating the farm to the latest CU and still nothing. Our dev environment also exhibits the same issue.